# How do you describe the proportionality for the function y = 1 / (1-x)?

Tags: functions

How do I describe the proportion between x and y for this function?

$$ y=\frac{1}{1-x} $$

When x increases, y increases. But they are not directly proportional with each other.
I understand that the equation is just a rotated hyperbola, but what terminologies do you use to describe the proportions when the expressions get somewhat complicated and you can't specify it such as a direct proportion or inverse square proportion where you use adjectives related to common constructions of the function such as position of variables or the exponent of the independent variable.

How do I describe that when x increases, y increases? I thought of using the word proportional and omitting the word direct but that feels so vague and it doesn't bring out the "x increases, y increases" out that well. The closest you could get is saying is that 1 - x is inversely proportional to y but I want to describe the relationship in terms of x and y.

This question is more about the wordings. I have to describe the proportion of x and y in a sentence and want to correctly do so. I am aware that there are appropriate ways to explain things in mathematics such as the usage of terms "direct proportion" and "inverse square proportion" so I know that I have to be concise with word usage.

Comment: This is not a power law, so $x$ does not have proportionality to $y$ in the normal sense of the word.

Comment: So what is a better word to use? The relationship? To pertain to how when x increases, y increases?

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way is to say "$y$ is inversely proportional to $1-x$".  If you want a more, purely verbal formulation you might say "$y$ is inversely proportional to the distance of $x$ from $1$", but this might be understood to refer to $y = \frac{1}{|1-x|}$".  Another, less ambiguous option might be "$y$ is inversely proportional to the amount by which $x$ is less than $1$".

Answer (score 0):

I guess you come from another area. In Mathematics there is no especial words for this relation for $x$ and $y$. To expect that every relation between two variables have a name is very very naive. There are infinitely many functions and describe them with formulas is much more practical that describe the relation with words. That's what Algebra was invented for, and it has become a very powerful tool. Trying to describe relations with words is to going many centuries backward.

Comment: I know that expecting every case to have a word variant is ridiculous. But I am not specifically after a special name. I would accept if the describing words encompass a general set of functions. I just want to present the idea that "as x increases, y increases" without sounding that they are directly proportional.